# Failure sending mail: An error has occurred during report processing.Mail will not be resent

Tags: reporting-services

An SSRS email subscription did not work this morning. The error message I saw is "Failure sending mail: An error has occurred during report processing.Mail will not be resent." When I checked the log files, I found out that there is an error in more than one dataset in the report. The report is reading data from Sharepoint. Please find below the error from the log file.

> Query execution failed for dataset 'WORK_PACKS'. ---> >System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.

> *ERROR:
> Throwing
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
> ,
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:
> An error has occurred during report processing. --->
> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException:
> Query execution failed for dataset 'CONSTRUCTION_ACTIVITIES'. --->
> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
> added.*

Comment: Have a read through this and then rewrite your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The issue is (poorly) described in the error message. I have never liked this error message, but I have seen it many times.

> Query execution failed for dataset 'WORK_PACKS'. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.

What that means is the dataset named WORK_PACKS has fields being returned with same name, or no name, more than once.

To fix it, find the query, and correct the query so that the field names are all unique. Make sure that what you are getting from SharePoint isn't giving you fields with the same name more than once. The will likely mean the RDL will need to be updated.

The report, and subscription, should work after you deploy the changes to the reporting server.